# Joomla: Show Header of my menu not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, menu, header

I have a problem with my menu for showing the header of my page. When I click **Edit** in the menu items, for example "About us" -> “Page Display Options”, I write the title of page for the browser and the header page and I choose "yes" for displaying the header of my page.

But when I see in the front end the page "about us", I see the title of page of browser twice. In top of page of my browser and in the top of my article and I don't see the header page.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't see the heading page?"

Comment: Sorry, i wanted write header page...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean with heading page.

Regarding showing the title twice, I guess you have the options set to display the article title. In the options of that menu item, set article title to **Not show**.

Other than that, it's possible that your template has overrides for the com_content, that manipulate the output of your article pages.

To identify if this is the case, assign temporary the default Joomla template (protostar) for that menu item and see what you get in the front-end.

### Update

It's your template that is doing this. There are template overrides, that are using the browser title of the menu item for the page you are looking and injecting it to the breadcrumbs content block.

I think there should be interesting things happening in your template.
Without knowing how your template is structured, a blind guess is that you might be able to spot the part of code in the template's index.php file, using FTP.

You are looking for the part that is outputting:

```
<h1 class="titlePage">
```

If you can spot this part of code, grab it (and a bit of its surroundings +- 3,4 lines) and paste it in your question for further investigation.

Comment: Thanks man for you reply. I edit my question. I don't see the header of page in my voice of my menu. In my page "about us" i call an article and in menu i choose for see the header of my page. But the problem is that i don't see the header but in its place I see the title of the browser page.

Comment: @Gabriel91, can you share the link to your page?

Comment: http://www.winetube.eu/en/about-winetube

Comment: You see? The title page it is repeated twice and the page header not exists.

Comment: @Gabriel91: check update in my answer

Comment: In index.php of my folder templates/mytheme/ in ftp i found only this code:

Comment: defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

if(class_exists('JV')){        
    $jv = JV::getInstance();
    $jv->initialise();
    echo $jv->render('index');
    
}else{
    JError::raiseError('JV Framework not found','Please install JV Framework to use this template.<br/>Go to <a href="http://joomlavi.com">http://joomlavi.com</a> or contact <a href="mailto:info@joomlavi.com">info@joomlavi.com</a> for infomation about JV Framework');
}

Comment: @Gabriel91, I see: It's this template: http://themeforest.net/item/all-in-one-multipurpose-joomla-template/9088328 - I don't know how this template is structured to guide you further. I see they have a support forum http://joomlavi.com/forum/forum/themeforest-template-support/all-in-one where you can ask. If you can't get help from there, post back here and we will find a way to help you, or maybe in the meantime someone who know the template might give you the exact steps you have to do.

Comment: I found the code man

Comment: <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)) : ?>
  <h1 class="titlePage"> <span> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?></span> </h1>
 <?php endif;

Comment: @Gabriel91 this seems ok. This question is gonna have a lot of search this or that... and currently I don't have all that time. It would be faster for me, if I had the template to have a quick look on it. If you like you could email me a zip with your template. let me know

Comment: Ok man, don't worry. Thank you for the moment. Meanwhile, I try to look in the template. Thank you.